# What constitutes an Oracle application?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have heard the term Oracle application used many times.  I've worked with PL/SQL for a few months now.  I've created queries, procedures, functions, etc.  I have never heard the word application used to describe any of these things.

So, what is an Oracle application?  Is it just an extended version of any of the things I mentioned above?

Comment: Don't get too worked up over nebulous words.

Comment: Okay, well I've heard the term used so often.  I ought to know what it means before I enter the IT field.

Comment: Could it be the just the start of "Oracle Application Server"?

Comment: It's context specific. Could mean many things. If you hear the term again - just ask what it is from whoever is speaking.

Comment: Well, let's just say in a business context.  A business wants to create applications using Oracle.  What does that mean?

Comment: An Oracle application is simply a software solution that happens to use one or more technologies created/owned by Oracle. Could be Oracle Application Server, or it could be something built in Forms, or in ADF, or Apex. Or it could be an application using any other technology but which happens to use an Oracle database as its data source.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle applications is an ERP and it's a product of Oracle corporation. It is a bundle application used for business transactions.